# Result Set Issue: Invalid operation: result set is closed. ERRORCODE=-4470, SQLSTATE=null

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, prepared-statement, resultset

I have the list of id's as follows '01/A', '02/B', '03/C', '04/D', '05/E'

MASTER TABLE

| ID | STATUS |
| --- | --- |
| 02/B | NA |
| 03/C | A |
| 05/E | A |

MASTER table I have the status of the above id's from conB Database. If id's are present in MASTER table, then I need to pick the status from MASTER table and insert into TEMP table in conA Database.

Note : 1st id : '01/A' and 4th id: '04/D' is not present in MASTER table.
So my code should skip those two id's and pick the status of other id's and insert into TEMP table.But I am getting and error message as "**Invalid operation: result set is closed. ERRORCODE=-4470, SQLSTATE=null**" at **rs.next()**

I am not sure where it went wrong. Anybody can help me out with this issue.

```
public int insertData(List<String> idList, Connection conA, Connection conB, )
        throws SQLException, SQLTransientConnectionException, Exception {
    int insertStatus = 0;
    String id = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < idList.size(); i++) {
        
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM MASTER WHERE ID LIKE '%" + idList.get(i) + "%')";       
        PreparedStatement ps = conB.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {         // Invalid operation: result set is closed. ERRORCODE=-4470, SQLSTATE=null
            try {
                id = rs.getString("ID");
                status = rs.getString("STATUS");
                
                String sql1 = "INSERT INTO TEMP (ID, STATUS) VALUES ('" + id + "','" + status + "')";               
                PreparedStatement ps1 = conA.prepareStatement(sql1);
                insertStatus = ps1.executeUpdate();
                ps1.close();
                
                log.info("Number of rows inserted " + insertStatus);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        ps.close();
        rs.close();
    }

    return insertStatus;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid operation: result set is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993975/invalid-operation-result-set-is-closed)

Comment: No above link didn't workout

Comment: @Mohan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25496610/invalid-operation-result-set-is-closed-errorcode-4470-sqlstate-null-db2-data-e might help

Comment: I checked the above link how to enable allowNextOnExhaustedResultSet property we are not using WAS